# Jenkins framework continuously registers and unregisters in Mesos

Tags: jenkins, mesos

I have an internal Jenkins server which I am trying to tie in to a Mesos environment we have running here in our office; however, I'm having a hard time keeping the Jenkins framework registered in Mesos:

[image: mesos-frameworks-completed]

Mesos Logs:

```
I0423 10:17:12.927397 23107 master.cpp:2737] Received SUBSCRIBE call 
for framework 'Jenkins Scheduler' at scheduler-5be6bf9c-7ebb-484e- 
80c4-f7e60b3400d6@127.0.1.1:33889
I0423 10:17:12.927868 23107 master.cpp:2813] Subscribing framework 
Jenkins Scheduler with checkpointing disabled and capabilities [  ]
E0423 10:17:12.928674 23110 process.cpp:2426] Failed to shutdown 
socket with fd 51: Transport endpoint is not connected
I0423 10:17:12.929549 23105 master.cpp:1381] Framework f3f7a58b-d7a5- 
4336-bc7e-69500d29c3ff-6973 (Jenkins Scheduler) at scheduler-5be6bf9c- 
7ebb-484e-80c4-f7e60b3400d6@127.0.1.1:33889 disconnected
I0423 10:17:12.929616 23105 master.cpp:3081] Deactivating framework 
f3f7a58b-d7a5-4336-bc7e-69500d29c3ff-6973 (Jenkins Scheduler) at 
scheduler-5be6bf9c-7ebb-484e-80c4-f7e60b3400d6@127.0.1.1:33889
I0423 10:17:12.929649 23105 master.cpp:3058] Disconnecting framework 
f3f7a58b-d7a5-4336-bc7e-69500d29c3ff-6973 (Jenkins Scheduler) at 
scheduler-5be6bf9c-7ebb-484e-80c4-f7e60b3400d6@127.0.1.1:33889
I0423 10:17:12.929675 23105 master.cpp:1396] Giving framework 
f3f7a58b-d7a5-4336-bc7e-69500d29c3ff-6973 (Jenkins Scheduler) at 
scheduler-5be6bf9c-7ebb-484e-80c4-f7e60b3400d6@127.0.1.1:33889 0ns to 
failover
E0423 10:17:12.929584 23110 process.cpp:2426] Failed to shutdown 
socket with fd 51: Transport endpoint is not connected
I0423 10:17:12.928707 23108 hierarchical.cpp:286] Added framework 
f3f7a58b-d7a5-4336-bc7e-69500d29c3ff-6973
I0423 10:17:12.930029 23108 hierarchical.cpp:415] Deactivated 
framework f3f7a58b-d7a5-4336-bc7e-69500d29c3ff-6973
I0423 10:17:12.930209 23103 master.cpp:6832] Framework failover 
timeout, removing framework f3f7a58b-d7a5-4336-bc7e-69500d29c3ff-6973 
(Jenkins Scheduler) at scheduler-5be6bf9c-7ebb-484e-80c4- 
f7e60b3400d6@127.0.1.1:33889
I0423 10:17:12.930279 23103 master.cpp:7717] Removing framework 
f3f7a58b-d7a5-4336-bc7e-69500d29c3ff-6973 (Jenkins Scheduler) at 
scheduler-5be6bf9c-7ebb-484e-80c4-f7e60b3400d6@127.0.1.1:33889
I0423 10:17:12.933053 23108 hierarchical.cpp:362] Removed framework 
f3f7a58b-d7a5-4336-bc7e-69500d29c3ff-6973`
```

I've tried setting the Slave Username to both `root` and `jenkins` explicitly without success. I've also added the `LIBPROCESS_IP` to my `/etc/default/jenkins` file.

[image: jenkins-mesos-cloud-settings]

[image: jenkins-mesos-cloud-advanced-settings]

Jenkins Logs:

```
`Apr 24, 2018 9:08:31 AM org.jenkinsci.plugins.mesos.Mesos getInstance
INFO: Adding a new cloud with unique cloud ID:  d761feab-44ad-47e2- 
aa54-aadc9e933cec
Apr 24, 2018 9:08:33 AM org.jenkinsci.plugins.mesos.MesosCloud 
restartMesos
INFO: Mesos master changed from 'null' to '10.0.x.x:5050'
Apr 24, 2018 9:08:33 AM org.jenkinsci.plugins.mesos.JenkinsScheduler 
<init>
INFO: JenkinsScheduler instantiated with jenkins http://10.0.x.x:8080 
and mesos 10.0.x.x:5050
Apr 24, 2018 9:08:34 AM org.jenkinsci.plugins.mesos.JenkinsScheduler 
init
INFO: Initializing the Mesos driver with options
Framework Name: Jenkins Scheduler
Principal: jenkins
Checkpointing: false
Apr 24, 2018 9:08:34 AM org.jenkinsci.plugins.mesos.MesosCloud 
provision
INFO: Provisioning Jenkins Slave on Mesos with 1 executors. Remaining 
excess workload: 0 executors)
INFO: Started provisioning MesosCloud from MesosCloud with 1 
executors. Remaining excess workload: 0
I0424 09:08:34.068917 13193 sched.cpp:232] Version: 1.5.0
I0424 09:08:34.075914 13189 sched.cpp:336] New master detected at 
master@10.0.x.x:5050
I0424 09:08:34.076942 13189 sched.cpp:351] No credentials provided. 
Attempting to register without authentication
Apr 24, 2018 9:08:41 AM 
org.jenkinsci.plugins.mesos.MesosComputerLauncher launch
INFO: Sending a request to start jenkins slave mesos-jenkins- 
bdfb011dfa074c809dfd98535bec30db-mesos
INFO: MesosCloud provisioning successfully completed. We have now 3 
computer(s)
Apr 24, 2018 9:09:00 AM 
org.jenkinsci.plugins.mesos.MesosWorkspaceBrowser getWorkspace
INFO: Nodes went offline. Hence fetching it through master`
```

- Jenkins version: 2.117
- Mesos plugin version: 0.16
- Mesos version: 1.2.0

Let me know if anything stands out to you. Thanks!

Comment: Do you have logs from jenkins?

Comment: @janisz, added above.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure exactly what did it, but I found that there was a version mismatch between the version of Mesos on the Jenkin's master and the Mesos master. I corrected that, but I had also replaced the 127.0.1.1 entry in the /etc/hosts file on Jenkins master with the actual IP and added the LIBPROCESS_IP environment variable.